# Rails: Password can't be blank with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, c9.io

I am trying to follow this tutorial ([Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up)) to create a valid user. Filling in the password fields still gives me the error "Password cannot be blank" and "Password has to be longer thank 6 letters". I tried creating a user through the rails console, and that worked fine. It is only when I try doing it through the website itself.

My user model looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  #before saving, make sure the email is in downcase
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

My user_controller looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#wrap_parameters :user, include: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #debugger
end
def new
  @user = User.new
end

# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
end

#POST /users
#POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) #params[:user])#user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      #flash[:success] = "Welcome to CourseBuddies!"

      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      redirect_to @user
    else
      #render 'new'
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /users/1
# PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /users/1
# DELETE /users/1.json
def destroy
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :pasword, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

This is my Migration file create_user:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
   create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.string :email
     t.string :password
     t.string :password_confirmation

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
```

end

I've tried different solutions found online like using "wrap_parameters" and such it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
# make pw digest "has_secure_password" use a stateofart hash function (bcrypt)
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13' #railsTuto said to get this, but already use postgresql
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~>0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

EDIT: My FORM

```
<%- #FIELDS FOR THE FORM %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>

    <%- #ERROR MESSAGES %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <br>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <br>  
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <br>  
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>


    <br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any kind of help or clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Update the question with the form code.

Comment: I see you have `pasword` instead of `password` in the `user_params`. Is that the typo? or you really have it like that? If you have it like that, then that is the reason for the error.

Comment: Can update the question with the log that is generated when you got the errors?

Comment: Okey, so I fixed my typo. I am able to sign up now! My mistake seemd to be the typo. And also, my login seems to be working properly too!

Comment: Glad to hear! Then you should mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual reason for the error is you **mistyped** `password` as `pasword` in your `user_params`. Fixing the typo should solve your problem.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION:

Okey, so after fixing my typo in my controller (pointed out by @Pavan), and also I removed the presence:true in my user model (@Divya Sharma), so it would look something like this:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

I can now properly sign up my user and login!

I think putting "allow_nil:true" actually just let me sign up because somehow, my password_fields was still "nil". I guess that was because of my typo's fault. Anyway, thanks guys for being so fast!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add  allow_nil: true in validation

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

As allow_nil: true will not allows to create empty string.

Comment: @Sedad.Kosovac has_secure_password automatically adds checks for existence and confirmation

Comment: @Myth you can remove presence: true from validation as has_secure_password will take care of it so your code will be like this: validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

Comment: I think the typo was my mistake! It works properly now :) (Without using the allow_nil: true). Thanks guys!